# Ansible known_hosts module with non-standard port

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

I'm provisioning a new server, and want to automatically add its public key to my local `known_hosts` file. My server is running on port `2222`.

`hosts`:

```
[remotes]
my_server ansible_host:42.42.42.42 ansible_port:2222
```

`playbook.yml`:

```
---
hosts: all
gather_facts: no
tasks:

- name: get host key
  local_action: command ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p {{ansible_port}} -H {{ansible_host}}
  register: host_key

- name: add host key
  when: host_key is success
  delegate_to: localhost
  known_hosts:
    name: "{{item}}"
    state: present
    hash_host: yes
    key: "{{host_key.stdout}}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ansible_host}}"
    - "{{inventory_hostname}}"
```

This adds new entries to the `known_hosts`.

BUT `ssh 42.42.42.42:2222` and `ssh my_server:2222` still show the unknown key warning.

I suspect it's because 1) I'm running on a non-standard port (the docs for the `known_host` module don't show an option for setting the port), or 2) something to do with the hashing option.

How do I do this?

Comment: "This adds new entries to the known_hosts". since it keeps throwing a warning, i would suggest you type "yes" to manually add the key, and then compare the 2 lines (1 line added by ansible PB, 1 added from your ssh command). also you can manually run the `sh-keyscan -t rsa -p {{ansible_port}} -H {{ansible_host}}` command and get the output on screen.

Comment: @ilias-sp Good idea! The one generated by the ansible script is `ssh-rsa` and the one generated manually when I type "yes" is `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`. The server is a vanilla ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The `known_hosts` module doesn't appear to have an option to specify the key type. What do you recommend I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution buried in an [old issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29236#issuecomment-328375453). The trick is to use `[host]:port` instead of `host`.

```
---
hosts: all
gather_facts: no
tasks:

# add entry to known_hosts for server's IP address
- name: get host key
  local_action: command ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p {{ansible_port}} -H {{ansible_host}}
  register: host_key
- name: add host key
  when: host_key is success
  delegate_to: localhost
  known_hosts:
    name: "[{{ansible_host}}]:{{ansible_port}}"            # <--- here
    state: present
    hash_host: yes
    key: "{{host_key.stdout}}"

# add entry to known_hosts for server's hostname
- name: get host key
  local_action: command ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p {{ansible_port}} -H {{inventory_hostname}}
  register: host_key
- name: add host key
  when: host_key is success
  delegate_to: localhost
  known_hosts:
    name: "[{{inventory_hostname}}]:{{ansible_port}}"      # <--- here
    state: present
    hash_host: yes
    key: "{{host_key.stdout}}"
```

I couldn't find a way to avoid the repetition, because `with_items` can't be applied to multiple tasks at once, so it's ugly but it works.

This allows `ssh 42.42.42.42:2222` and `ssh my_server:2222` without prompts (though `my_server` must be defined in `/etc/hosts` and/or `~/.ssh/config`).